# How to get the number of users that made specific events from Analytics 4 API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Right now I'm using these details to get the number of conversions, but in the Analytics 4 dashboard I can see 2 columns, one for conversions and one for users, which is usually a lot less than the number of conversions. but I don't know exactly what metrics should I use to get that information only for events that are counted as conversions.

```
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => $sdate,
            'end_date' => $edate,
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'eventName',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'conversions',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
```

Comment: you should explain a bit more, anyhow maybe you can sum the retrieved records from your table saved in database.